# Warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type

Tags: c

I'm testing this function that's supposed to read input from the user but it throws me a segmentation fault

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LENGTH 10

int 
readinput(char *input)
{
    int c;
    int i=0;
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')  //Here is where the warning occurs.
    {
        input[i]=c;
        i++;
    }
    input[i]=0;
    if(strlen(input)>0)
    {
        if(isalpha(input[0]) && input[1]=='-' && isalpha(input[2]) && strlen(input)==3)
            return 0;
        else if(!strcmp(input, "quit"))
            return 1;
        else if(!strncmp(input, "save ", 5))
            return 2;
        else if(!strcmp(input, "undo"))
            return 3;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
   char *str;
   printf("write a string\n");
   int nr=readinput(str);
   printf("%d\n", nr);
   printf("%s\n", str);
   return 0;
}
```

I did notice the stupid error I made, but still, segmentation fault, why?

Comment: `c` will never equal `'/n'`. I think you mean `c != '\n'`.

Comment: `getchar` returns an **int**.

Comment: The `getchar()` function returns an `int` and not a `char`.  If you assign the result to a `char`, you will get confused — but the manner of being confused depends on whether `char` is a signed or unsigned type in your compiler.  If `char` is signed, then a valid character (often ÿ or U+00FF or SMALL LATIN LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS in a single-byte code set) is interpreted as EOF when it should not be.  If `char` is unsigned, then the value will never equal EOF.

Comment: You're getting the segmentation fault because you've not allocated space for the string that `readinput()` is given to write to.

Comment: You're not initializing `str` to anything, so it's still a NULL pointer. Thus, seg fault.

Comment: @lc. you're right that `str` is uninitialized; it is not, however, initialized to a null pointer except by accident or implementation decision; the standard certainly does not guarantee any specific value for it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also very true. As you say, my comment more correctly would be, it's a pointer to *somewhere* and just often happens to be NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segmentation fault arises because you've passed an uninitialized pointer to the function `readinput()`.  You need to do something like:

```
char str[4096];

int nr = readinput(str);
```

You should pass in a length of the array so that the called code can verify that it does not overflow its boundaries.  Or you can live dangerously and decide that 4096 is big enough, which it probably will be until someone is trying to break your program deliberately.

---

The original compiler warning was because the multi-character constant `'/n'` has a value (of type `int`) which is outside the range of values that can be stored in a `char`, so when `c` is promoted to `int`, the `!=` comparison with the (implementation-defined) value of `'/n'` is bound to be true.  Hence the warning:

```
Warning: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type
```

All multi-character character constants have implementation-defined values.  There are no portable multi-character character constants.

ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.4.4.4 Character constants

> ¶10 ... The value of an integer character constant containing more than one character (e.g.,
>   `'ab'`), or containing a character or escape sequence that does not map to a single-byte
>   execution character, is implementation-defined. ...

Answer (score 2):

This is because EOF is defined (in my compiler) as -1 and char is unsigned byte. so it is always !=

Answer (score 2):

```
 c != '/n' is wrong

 change it to 

  c != '\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

`c != '/n'` should be `c != '\n'`

`\` is an escape character which indicates, in the case where it is followed by `n`, a newline.  `/n` will be treated as two distinct characters, which cannot properly be compared to a single `char` variable.

As for you segmentation fault, you'll need to allocate some space for `str` in your `main` function:

```
char* str = malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_STRING_LENGTH);
```

or

```
char str[MAX_STRING_LENGTH];
```

but you'll also have to ensure you don't try to read a string that has more characters than your `str` array can hold.

Answer (score 2):

It faults because you never allocated space for `str` and it points to a random location which causes readinput to try to store data in a place that doesn't exist.